# WooCommerce- product variations values are filtered

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using the latest WooCommerce (2.2.10).

My select list values are URL links, when I hit the Add To Cart button the variation values are filtered and some characters are removed from the URL.

For example: 
If the selected URL is "xyz.com", it will be filtered to "xyz_com". Or http slash slash will result in removing the slashes.

- How can I remove this filter?
- Where is the functionality of "Add To Cart" button defined? In other words; what happens after the button is clicked, and whether I can change it or not.

Comment: Any reason you can't update to the latest version of woocommerce? 2.2.1 is 9 versions back. Current is 2.2.10

Comment: the WC version is not the issue here. I use the latest.